# What is the advantage of going last in Smallworld

Tags: small-world

What are the advantages/strategies of going last? Based off of my understanding:

a) you get worse options in choosing
b) last place in starting location
c) on last round, others can attack you to reduce your coins with no reciprocal effect.

Suggestion: Force every player to decline in last turn (like stout) which allows other players to have more open lands. This would help because they can't reduce other player's scores but they could potentially boost their own.

What do you think?? :):)

Comment: Examine your premise, specifically (a). What is the cost for selecting a race higher in the que?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based, as "what do you think of my homebrew rule?" isn't a problem we can solve - it's just canvassing opinions. (Also who says there *is* any advantage in going last?)

Answer (score 1):

You are only disadvantaged if everyone else is trying to do nothing about trying to win.

The guy who goes first gets an advantage and if no one punishes him, he wins.  If you as last place sit idly by and let everyone do their best, you lose.  This is an important point in many games.

Answer (score 0):

While I think going later tends to be a disadvantage, one case it can help is if a powerful aggressive race (like the Flames from Smallworld Underground) appears early. If the first player takes them, she's at a disadvantage because there's no one to attack. If she doesn't take them, she's at a disadvantage because a later player can beat her up using that race.

Ultimately though, as LeppyR64 says in his answer, in a highly-interactive 3+ player game like this one it's up to the players to counteract such imbalances by attacking the leader.